# ASP.Net: Work on XML data from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, database

I have an issue on which methods or technology i can work on, so as to visualize on a web application a simple information from a database.
The data is only xml, like this :
[It's one data for 1 element](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1P2-BHpMTUQEyoaAub2NBebpWVREztW7vGsh3o8sKXmI/edit)

It's a very heavy element ans it's not under my control and i can't modify the datafield, but the only things i want is to save the value from the XML Elements "FormId" and "TimeLastModified", so as to display this on my web application.
I would like to work on code-behind with ASP.Net.
A kind person on this website told me about **System.Xml.XmlDocument**, but i want to connect this to the database with SqlConnection and save these value on string, so as to use it later.
Is it possible ?

**EDIT** : the database saves id, name and Content of templates and forms from a design software. Every Elements are saved on xml data in the Content field.
The designer who works on that app can make modification on the templates, but there are links between templates and forms, and a simple modification can modify one or many forms. 
My job is to display on a web application each templates modify (with the "TimeLastModified" xml element), and the forms which are associated to (with the "FormId" xml element).

[table Template structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CGN1.jpg)

[table Template datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BykvO.jpg)

Comment: Your question is not very clear and lacks information. You can't "connect" System.Xml.XmlDocument to the database as it has no meaning. You have to query the database, get the XML as a string and parse it using System.Xml.XmlDocument, you can get its elements by name. Those are different problems try to solve each separately.

Comment: Ok, i thought that i have to use the **xmldocument.Load** method.

Comment: What kind of database you will connect to ? can you query those specific elements you need ?

Comment: My data base is composed of two main tables : Template and Form. Each table is composed of 3 fields : Id, Name and Content. It's in this last field that i have the fully xml i have to work on (as the google doc you can see higher).

Comment: Try to reformulate your questions. And give more details on what behavior you want to implement, use diagrams if necessary.

Comment: i edited my question so as to give you more details. I'm so sorry because i'm not fluent in english and it's a bit hard for me to explain with details and to be understood.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017, you can do this:
[image: Visual Studio 2017: C# Paste XML as Classes]

And you will get classes to read and write your XML:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyXML
{
    // NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Root
    {

        private RootStorageObject storageObjectField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public RootStorageObject StorageObject
        {
            get
            {
                return this.storageObjectField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.storageObjectField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RootStorageObject
    {

        private RootStorageObjectProperty[] propertiesField;

        private string nameField;

        private string idField;

        private string typeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Property", IsNullable = false)]
        public RootStorageObjectProperty[] Properties
        {
            get
            {
                return this.propertiesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.propertiesField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.typeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class RootStorageObjectProperty
    {

        private string nameField;

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Then you can Serialize or Deserialize your object to XML

```
   /// <summary>
   /// The serialize.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="value">
   /// The value.
   /// </param>
   /// <param name="xmlWriterSettings">
   /// The xml writer settings.
   /// </param>
   /// <typeparam name="T">
   /// The object of the type T.
   /// </typeparam>
   /// <returns>
   /// The value in <see cref="string"/> that correspond the xml.
   /// </returns>
   /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
   /// The value cannot be null.
   /// </exception>
   public static string Serialize<T>(T value, XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = null)
   {
       if (value == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentException("value");
       }

       var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

       var settings = xmlWriterSettings ?? new XmlWriterSettings
       {
           Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false),
           Indent = false,
           OmitXmlDeclaration = false
       };

       using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
       {
           using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
           {
               serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
           }

           return textWriter.ToString();
       }
   }

/// <summary>
/// The deserialize.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xml">
/// The xml.
/// </param>
/// <param name="xmlReaderSettings">
/// The xml Reader Settings.
/// </param>
/// <typeparam name="T">
/// The object of the type T.
/// </typeparam>
/// <returns>
/// The object of the type <see cref="T"/>.
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
/// The xml value cannot be null.
/// </exception>
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml, XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("xml");
    }

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    var settings = xmlReaderSettings ?? new XmlReaderSettings();

    // No settings need modifying here
    using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

source: http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/c-generic-xml-serialize-deserialize/

Comment: ,Am i forced to serialize these objects ? I just need to store the value from "FormId" in a string, and use it with a SQL query so as to look for the data from the Form table in the database.

Comment: I like to work with objects, so I recommend almost always serialize, work with the object, then deserialize to XML